# JcaX509CertificateConverter cannot find the required provider BC

Tags: java, bouncycastle

I don't understand why BC is not being recognized as provider in the setProvider("BC"). I have downloaded the latest BouncyCastle http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html (from 2013) and imported it successfully. However, when I run the following code:

```
X509Certificate crt=(X509Certificate)(new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider("BC").getCertificate(crthold));
```

I get an exception that provider `BC` was not found.

Does anyone please has an idea on how this could be fixed?
Below is the error message I am getting

```
org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaX509CertificateConverter$ExCertificateException: cannot find required provider:no such provider: BC
    at org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaX509CertificateConverter.getCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at client.ClientService.genCert(ClientService.java:399)
```

Comment: I really feel bad about the question because it was a really very easy findout. I just added an instance of the BouncyCastleProvider instead of BC and it worked perfectly. I am adding the answer for those who might be one day in the same situation
   X509Certificate crt=(X509Certificate)(new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider()).getCertificate(crthold));

Comment: You can also call Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider()); before you need provider or in application entry point.

Comment: @zeroday you should add your comment as an answer and accept it so that others can find it easier in the future.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just added an instance of the BouncyCastleProvider instead of BC and it worked perfectly. I am adding the answer for those who might be one day in the same situation:

```
X509Certificate crt=(X509Certificate)(new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider()).getCertificate(crthold));
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to [install the Bouncy Castle provider](http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/Provider+Installation) in order to retrieve it by name.  This can either be done via the `java.security` properties file, or via the following method call:

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
```

You can then refer to this provider by `BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME`.